# TabBar Navigation in a Card Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a home page that uses Scaffold and a bottom navigation. In the body of the Scaffold, I have a page that contains 2 Card Widgets. I am trying to implement a "sub" tabBar navigation for the second card that is independent of the bottom navigation. Is there a way to implement tabbed bar navigation for a Card widget? I have tried using Scaffold but the tab bar height is rather too large. From the docs, this seems to be due to the flexiblespace Widget but I haven't found a way to eliminate/scale it, pointers will be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyTabs()));
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => new MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Pages"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            ),
        bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            child: new TabBar(controller: controller, tabs: <Tab>[
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
            ])),
        body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
          new First(),
          new Second(),
          new Third()
        ]));
  }
}
class First extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstState createState() => new FirstState();
}

class FirstState extends State<First> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller1 = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller1.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children: [
      new Expanded(
        child: new Card(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Icon(Icons.favorite,
                    size: 150.0, color: Colors.redAccent))),
      ),
      new Expanded(child: new Card(
          child: new Center(
              child: new Container(
                  child: new Scaffold(
                      appBar: new AppBar(
                          bottom: new TabBar(
                              controller: controller1,
                              tabs: <Tab>[
                                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
                                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
                                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                              ]
                          )),
                      body: new TabBarView(
                          controller: controller1,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("Hello"),
                            new Text("world"),
                            new Text("Hi")
                          ]
                      )
                  )
              )
          ))),
    ]);
  }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: new Center(
            child: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150.0, color: Colors.redAccent)
        )
    );
  }
}

class Third extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: new Center(
            child: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150.0, color: Colors.redAccent)
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Code is modified from [here](https://github.com/bramvbilsen/Flutter-TabBar-tutorial/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 2):

This code should do what you want. You don't need to use a nested `Scaffold` or `AppBar`, a simple `Column` is all you need.

[image: screenshot]

As an aside, you might want to consider a `BottomNavigationBar` since `TabBar` is a Material widget that normally appears on top of the content it's navigating.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyTabs()));
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => new MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Pages"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        child: new TabBar(controller: controller, tabs: <Tab>[
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
        ])),
      body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
        new First(),
        new Second(),
        new Third()
      ]));
  }
}

class First extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstState createState() => new FirstState();
}

class FirstState extends State<First> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller1 = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3, initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller1.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children: [
      new Expanded(
        child: new Card(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Icon(Icons.favorite,
              size: 150.0, color: Colors.redAccent))),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new Card(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new TabBarView(
                  controller: controller1,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Hello"),
                    new Text("world"),
                    new Text("Hi")
                  ]
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: new TabBar(
                  controller: controller1,
                  tabs: <Tab>[
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Center(
        child: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150.0, color: Colors.redAccent)
      )
    );
  }
}

class Third extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Center(
        child: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150.0, color: Colors.redAccent)
      )
    );
  }
}
```